# Block diagonalizing a Hermitian matrix

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition, change-of-basis

I have an 8*8 Hermitian matrix and I want to Block diagonalize it to four 2*2 matrices. Is there any general way to do that?! If it's not please help me for the specific one that is posted bellow.(" i " stands for imaginary unit)

\begin{bmatrix}
J-\mu & a+ib & M & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a-ib & -J-\mu & 0 & M  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
M & 0 & J-\mu & -a-ib & 0 & 0 & 0 & P \\
0 & M & -a+ib & -J-\mu & 0 & 0 & -P & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -J+\mu & a-ib & -M & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a+ib & J+\mu & 0 & -M \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -P & -M  & 0 & -J+\mu & -a+ib \\
0 & 0 & P & 0 & 0 & -M  & -a-ib & J+\mu \\
\end{bmatrix},

and I want to covert it to :

\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
C & D & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & E & F & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & G & H & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & H & I & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J & K & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & L & M \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & N & O \\
\end{bmatrix},